# Try catch within array initialization

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch

quick question. Is there any way to make this possible?

```
int array [] =  new int [
     (try {
          Integer.parseInt (/*get string input here*/);
          }
     catch (NumberFormatException e){
     //error handling here
     )
];
```

Comment: Yes. Do it *before* you initialize the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not legal syntax. Try something like this:

```
int number;
try
{
     number = Integer.parseInt (/*get string input here*/);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
     //error handling here
}

int array [] =  new int [2];
array[0] = number;
```

It's a little verbose, but welcome to Java, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Like Brian said.. You need to move your try /catch block above the array initialization.

```
int i;

try{
  string myString = "1";
 i = Integer.parseInt(myString)l
} catch(NumberFormatException e){
  //handle
}

int array [] = new int[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

See below...

```
int myArray[] = new int[10];
String tempString = "1";
try {
    for (int i=0;i<=9;i++) {
        tempString += i;
        myArray[i]=Integer.parseInt(tempString);
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // print error
} catch (Exception e) {
    // print error
}
```